# How to pass this to another function and get $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm passing `this` inside an `each` loop (DOM object) to another function but in that function, there is a part of the code that uses `$(this)` (jQuery object). I wonder how can I get the jQuery object from the DOM object. I thought that using `$(obj)` will work but it won't!!!

I explain this more with an example.

I want to extract some part of the following function to another method:

```
    addWidgetControls : function () {
    //...            
    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
        var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
        if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
            $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();    
            }).click(function () {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                        opacity: 0    
                    },function () {
                        $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
                return false;
            }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
        }
    });        
},
```

Below is the extracted method (not working):

```
    addWidgetControls: function () {
    //...
    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
        iNettuts.doWidget(this);
    });
},

doWidget: function (widg) {
    $ = jQuery;
    settings = iNettuts.settings;
    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(widg.id);
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
        $('<a href="#" class="remove"></a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }).click(function () {
            $(widg).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, function () {
                $(widg).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                    widg.remove();
                });
            });

            return false;
        }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, widg));
    }
    //...
```

The code in the `doWidget` function is copied from the original method (`addWidgetControls`), except I've changed `this` to `widg` anywhere in it. But it won't work.

I've investigated the problem and copied the exacted code inside the `each` loop of the original function (`addWidgetControls`) and replaced all `$(widg)` into `$(this)` and didn't replace `widg` with `this`. And it worked properly. (code below:)

```
addWidgetControls : function () {
    //...

    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
        var wid = this;
        var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(wid.id);
        if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
            $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();    
            }).click(function () {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                        opacity: 0    
                    },function () {
                        $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });
                return false;
            }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, wid));
        }
    });        
},
```

This means that somehow `$(this)` is different than `$(widg)` when `this` is the same as `widg`

PS: I've got this code from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/)

Comment: It's not clear to me what worked properly and what didn't, and if the code is the working or non-working version.

Comment: I'm sorry. Please read it again. I've added more code to explain it. I hope it's clear.

Comment: Not sure why you are adding all the confusion with all the 'this' business.
Why don't you cache your $(this) calls to a local variable (to avoid confusion and for [better performance](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects)), this way, you know exactly which this is being used!

Comment: You mean something like this: `var jwid = $(this)` and passing it to the function? If so, I've tried this and it didn't work either!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of the answers. The problem is solved and it was really interesting and easy to find! The `this` pointer, as we all know, is different from time to time, and in this case, there were only 3 instances of `this` that should've been replaced with `widg`. @kamaci's answer as well as some other answers hinted me to solve it. So here is the final code:

```
addWidgetControls: function () {
    var iNettuts = this,
        $ = this.jQuery,
        settings = this.settings,
        func = this.doWidget;

    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
        func(this);
    });
},

doWidget: function (wid) {
    var $ = iNettuts.jQuery,
        settings = iNettuts.settings;

    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(wid.id);
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
        $('<a href="#" class="remove"></a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }).click(function () {
            $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                opacity: 0
            }, function () {
                $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });

            return false;
        }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, wid));
    }

    if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) {
        $('<a href="#" class="collapse"></a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }).toggle(function () {
            $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '-38px 0' })
                    .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                        .find(settings.contentSelector).hide();
            return false;
        }, function () {
            $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '' })
                    .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                        .find(settings.contentSelector).show();
            return false;
        }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector, wid));
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you I think that you should keep `widg` variable as you did and keep `$(this)` instead of `$(widg)`. You will call that function in a loop because of `each` and `this` will change every time. However if you use `widg` every time this varible will point the same  `this` inside of that function you call your function and this should be what you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think that `iNettuts.doWidget(this);` will pass `this` to the `doWidget` function as `widg` and with each loop the `this` (hence `widg`) will be updated. Am I wrong? Please read the question one more time, I've explained it more.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori At your first and working code all `this` variables points different things. Your last code is correct. You should use `this` instead of `widg` because each `this` will point that functions they are inside it not to parameter passed `widg` that upper level ``this.

Comment: I know but I think I've taken care of that by passing `this` to the function and using it as `widg`. Yes, I've tried that, no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because of this :

```
 widg.wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
    widg.remove();
 });
```

You forgot to wrap **widg** with $() :

```
 $(widg).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
    $(widg).remove();
 });
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I've copied the wrong version. I've done that but it didn't help either.

Comment: That's OK. My last post may help you ;) .

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you would like to use the [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method.

```
addWidgetControls : function () {
//...            
   $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
       iNettuts.doWidget.call(this);
   }); 
},
doWidget: function(){
    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
        $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();    
        }).click(function () {
                $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                    opacity: 0    
                },function () {
                    $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                });
            return false;
        }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. Other than that, the whole point of extracting this method is that I want to call this object later using this: `iNettuts.doWidget($newItem.get(0));`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set a context of a function (the `this` assignment) you can use `apply` or `call`.  Here is an example:

```
var obj = "testing";

var func = function() {
  alert(this);
}

func();
func.apply(obj);
```

Now, run the code in a browser (I used firebug).

The first alert will be the window object because the default context of all objects trickles down to the window object.  The second alert we've set the context to be the string "testing" so that is what the alert will say.

So, as fflorent used `call`, you can also use `apply`.

#### Update

when you are using the code:

```
$(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
    iNettuts.doWidget(this);
});
```

`this` refers the object that the .each() method is on.  Did you want it to work this way?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but I tried both `apply` and `call`, no luck!!

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, but if you take a look at my own answer, you'll see there are a couple of `this`s that I wasn't aware of their difference from this `this`.

Comment: @AlirezaNoori yeah, it is hard to keep track of the `this`es sometimes. Did it answer your question or are you still having trouble?

Comment: Yes, thanks to you guys, my problem is now solved. I'm waiting to select the answer.